# Vagrant and boot2docker rsync auto problems

Tags: synchronization, vagrant, boot2docker, vagrantfile

Hi I'm having problems with rsync_auto with Vagrant and using Docker as a provider, that means that I have a Docker Host VM (virtualBox).

Vagrant syncs my folder only in provision time(only once).

I want to sync my files on change (my machine <--> docker host)

```
config.vm.box = "dduportal/boot2docker"

config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/project", type: "rsync",
rsync__auto: true
```

When I run **vagrant rsync-auto** it syncs my files correctly. but I want that Vagrant sync automatically. There is no error after **Vagrant up**

```
dockerhost: Rsyncing folder: /Users/user/workspace/docker/provisioning/ => /project
```

I already tested to change /project directory permissions 777, does not work as well.

Environment:

- Mac: OS X Yosemite, 10.10.5
- Vagrant: 1.8.1
- Docker: 1.10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tests I decided to use NFS (Network File System) instead of rsync, this allows me to have synced my machine and the Docker Host. And it works great.

This configuration allows me to manage that.

```
#sync local files to the docker host VM
config.vm.synced_folder "../", "/vagrant", type: "nfs", mount_options: ["nolock", "vers=3", "udp"], id: "nfs-sync"
```

Reference:
https://github.com/dduportal/boot2docker-vagrant-box/issues/48